# How to get element and html from window.open js function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I am trying to open a popup like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var popup = window.open('mypage.php', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');
    var dom = popup.document.body;
    for (i in dom) {
        console.log(dom[i]);
    }
});
```

Now what I want to do is to get the html from the popup window and also be able to use maybe a jQuery function from the window.opener (the page that opened the popup)

PS. In the console there are a lot of things printed but no html source.

Use this to try: http://jsfiddle.net/JRqTy/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this? The solutions below are not working for me. I'm using React, but I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var html = popup.document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

**EDIT**

The window is not loaded immediately. Something like this will work, assuming that you're not attempting to violate the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var popup = window.open('[Your URL HERE]', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');
    
    popup.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log(popup.document.documentElement.outerHTML) }, 2000);
    }  
});​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/JRqTy/3/).

**Note:** If you control both the parent and the child source, you could also have the child invoke a method on the parent that passes in it's html:

**Child Window**

```
// Call when body is loaded
function SendHtmlToParent() {
    window.opener.HtmlReceiver(document.outerHTML);
}
```

**Parent**

```
function HtmlReceiver(html) {
    console.log(html);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the fiddle example is not working, nor can I get it working myself. I've spent several hours and cannot get windows or iframes working with access by the parent/opener. Firefox 63.0.3 (64bit)

Comment: @DavidSpector, are you violating the same origin policy? Are the parent and child window on the same domain, or are both of the domains under your control with a valid same origin policy?

Comment: They are not only in the same domain but in the same directory. I'm working on a tool to help design websites and it never has to work across different domains. It does have to have a window or pane showing the page under development and be able to manipulate its elements. Thanks for asking. Getting help is hard enough without getting accusations.

Comment: Please update your  same-origin policy link - it's dead.

Answer (score 1):

Wait...

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open() returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

And if you wait, you will get this error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.google.co.il/ from frame with URL http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

So it can be done with google, unless you're working there...

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JRqTy/2/)

If you open something "valid" it will work fine.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JRqTy/4/)

Comment: @OscarJara. We cleaned all the thread from comments. it was a mess.

Comment: This fiddle "working demo" is also not working, 6 years later.

Comment: I think waiting for the new window or iframe to load is key to making this work, and none of the Mozilla or other tutorials I can find mention this!