# How to get a different window's html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to open a new window using a url, grab its html as a string and display it in the console of the original window.

From [How to get element and html from window.open js function with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810035/how-to-get-element-and-html-from-window-open-js-function-with-jquery) , I tried:

```
console.log('response', url)
    var popup = window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');

popup.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log( 'hi',popup.document.documentElement.outerHTML) }, 2000);
}
```

The popup window is created, but I don't see the popup's html in the original window's console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the given url of the same domain where the popup is launched? Which browser are you working with?

Comment: The url is http://stackoverflow.com/, I'm working with firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not on the same domain, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible as it's not possible with an iframe: [Get HTML inside iframe using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery).

However, if you own both pages, you should be able to use what is described in the first answer to the SO question you linked to ([How to get element and html from window.open js function with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810035/how-to-get-element-and-html-from-window-open-js-function-with-jquery))

> **Note:** If you control both the parent and the child source, you could also have the child invoke a method on the parent that passes in
>   it's html:
>
> **Child Window**
>
> ```
> // Call when body is loaded
> function SendHtmlToParent() {
>     window.opener.HtmlReceiver(document.outerHTML);
> }
> ```
>
> **Parent**
>
> ```
> function HtmlReceiver(html) {
>     console.log(html);
> }
> ```

Comment: If you try the fiddle on the question you linked to, and change the URL to stackoverflow.com , you'll see that it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/JRqTy/394/