# In React how to get response from URL. Note:- URL hit is not an ajax hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

```
onButtonClick= (authLink) => {

            if(authLink){
                window.open(authLink, '_blank');
            }
     };
```

response from this url is :-

```
{
"statusCode":"STATUS_OK",
"statusMessage":"The operation was successful.",
"statusUserMessage":"The operation was successful.",
"authToken":"AJFCNA",
"opaqueData":
    {"accessToken":"SJD.skb.zV-sdb-kajsb-dkjbc"},
     "authTokenValidity":21600,
    }
}
```

How to get this response in my code, I want to get the value for the key `authToken`.
I have no idea. what can I do for this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "URL hit is not an ajax hit" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "URL hit is not an ajax hit". You should be able to get the data using AJAX:

```
fetch(authLink)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { console.log(data.authToken) })
  .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
```

If for some reason you can't / don't want to use AJAX, and really need to call `window.open()`, you can check some interesting answers here: [How to get element and html from window.open js function with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810035/how-to-get-element-and-html-from-window-open-js-function-with-jquery)

Comment: Url hit means any anchor <a href=""/> tag click

Comment: So you can use Ajax in the handler if you want to, right?